# Normalizing a plot by introducing a variable

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, legending, maximize, axeslabel

I am trying to plot the graph between P and x. My teacher wants me to normalize this graph by introducing a constant $k$ to get $P/k^2$ on the y-axis and $xk$ on the x-axis. I did that by doing a short cut, by manually seeing the max value of P and plotted the graph by doing $P/0.0035$ which was the maximum value of $P$ from graph. But how can I do it efficiently by using mathematical commands? My code is below:

```
gamma = 1/Sqrt[1 - D[r (-1 + 1/v) + ArcTanh[r], r]^-2]
```

Then I plotted $p-x$ in the limits, ${x,-1,1}$ as follows:
**Definition:**

```
power = 1/(6 Pi) D[gamma, r]^2
```

**Plot**

```
pow = Plot[{power/0.0035 /. v -> 1/2, power/0.0035 /. v -> 1/3, 
   power/0.0035 /. v -> 1/4}, {r, -1, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> {Style["x\[Kappa]", Black, FontFamily -> "Times", 
     FontSize -> 15], Style["P/\[Kappa]^2", Black, FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 15]}, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Times", Black, Bold}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thickness[0.005]}, {Purple, 
     Thickness[0.005]}, {Yellow, Thickness[0.005]}}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[LineLegend[{Directive[Thickness[0.1], Red], 
      Directive[Thickness[0.1], Purple], 
      Directive[Thickness[0.1], Yellow]}, {Style["s=1/2", 11, Bold], 
      Style["s=1/3", 11, Bold], Style["s=1/4", 11, Bold]}, 
     LegendMarkerSize -> {{21, 15}}], {0.6, 0.6}]]
```

If I introduce a $k^2$ quantity, my x-axis should also be scaled. How can I completely normalize this graph with both axes calling through the quantity $k$ using the mathematica commands? I have mathematica 9.0.

Comment: `k = Sqrt[MaxValue[{power, 1/4 <= v <= 1/2, -1 <= r <= 1}, {r, v}]]` which evaluates to `(2 Sqrt[2/π])/27` The approximate value of `k^2` is `0.00349311`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use "Maximize" to get the r value of the maximum. With this you get the maximal value for P: pmax:

```
gamma = 1/Sqrt[1 - D[r (-1 + 1/v) + ArcTanh[r], r]^-2];
power = 1/(6 Pi) D[gamma, r]^2;
pmax = power /. v -> 1/2 /. 
   Maximize[{power /. v -> 1/2, -1 <= r <= 1}, r][[2]];
pow = Plot[{power/pmax /. v -> 1/2, power/pmax /. v -> 1/3, 
   power/pmax /. v -> 1/4}, {r, -1, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> {Style["x\[Kappa]", Black, FontFamily -> "Times", 
     FontSize -> 15], 
    Style["P/\[Kappa]^2", Black, FontFamily -> "Times", 
     FontSize -> 15]}, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Times", Black, Bold}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thickness[0.005]}, {Purple, 
     Thickness[0.005]}, {Yellow, Thickness[0.005]}}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[LineLegend[{Directive[Thickness[0.1], Red], 
      Directive[Thickness[0.1], Purple], 
      Directive[Thickness[0.1], Yellow]}, {Style["s=1/2", 11, Bold], 
      Style["s=1/3", 11, Bold], Style["s=1/4", 11, Bold]}, 
     LegendMarkerSize -> {{21, 15}}], {0.6, 0.6}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks dude, that's helpful.